# Does Qt Creator support incremental build?

Tags: c++, netbeans, qt-creator

My current work is transplanting one project in Netbeans to Qt Creator, and

> NetBeans IDE supports automatic checking of file dependencies and does its best to make incremental rebuild work correctly

at https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/depchecking.html. My question is weather Qt Creator have these abilities or need some plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'includes' dependency checking is the default behavior of every compiler tool chain. It is done by mingw, or visual, .... 
So it is the default behavior on QtCretor. It is not an option.
If you want to rebuild all, you have to ask it explicitly.